# Cover no-op functions with Jest and Enzyme

Tags: jestjs, enzyme, istanbul

In my React component I have some no-op functions, which basically is just placeholders for a functions. I have Istanbul test coverage, and it's complain on no-op function coverage:
[image]

Is there any ways to cover it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make Instanbul ignore noop functions we can use `/* istanbul ignore next */` mentioned [here](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/blob/master/ignoring-code-for-coverage.md#ignoring-code-for-coverage-purposes).

For you example coverage, you could do something like

```js
const defaultContext = {
  activeInput: null,
  removeFocus: /* istanbul ignore next */ () => {},
  focusInput: /* istanbul ignore next */ () => {},
}
```

Or you could define an isolated noop function and reuse whenever needs

```js
/* istanbul ignore next */
function noop() {}

const defaultContext = {
  activeInput: null,
  removeFocus: noop,
  focusInput: noop,
}
```